# Should be possible to create a mapping key from a struct object in solidity

Tags: solidity

Should be possible to create a mapping key from a struct object. like bellow

```
struct A {
  string a;
  address b;
}
```

what methods or operator should be added to struct for defining bellow type:

```
mapping (A => uint256) map;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question gives the following error:

> TypeError: Only elementary types, user defined value types, contract types or enums are allowed as mapping keys.

`struct A` is a user defined type. But it's a reference type ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/types.html#structs)) - not a value type - so it's not allowed as a `mapping` key.

Having said that, you can produce a hash of the `struct` values and use this hash as a key of the `mapping`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    struct A {
        string a;
        address b;
    }
    mapping (bytes32 => uint256) map;

    function set(A calldata key, uint256 value) external {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(key));
        map[hash] = value;
    }

    function get(A calldata key) external view returns (uint256) {
        bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encode(key));
        return map[hash];
    }
}
```